# DriveApp.remove(folder) using REST API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to 'hide' a folder from the users Drive root, as it contains mostly junk Google Docs. I don't want to actually trash it, or use the appData storage as I can't then convert things to Google Docs.

In Apps Script, I can call `DriveApp.remove(folder)` and the file is given no parents at all, not even the root. I've tried calling the `create` method with `"parents": []` but the folder is still created in the root.

Is there a way to make this happen with the REST API?

Comment: Whoever voted to close: This is clearly on-topic. OP is attempting to find a programatic way to do something using a specific API. They have indicated a way to do it using a different API, suggesting it is possible. They have referenced the API they want to use with a method they've tried that didn't work. How much more on topic can you get?

Comment: have you tried patching the folder and setting parents to null?

Comment: documentation seams to say that you should use removeParents in an update request if you remove them all I wonder what would happen

Comment: Cheers guys, I've posted an answer. Looks like we all came to the same conclusion :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Supplying an empty `parents` list means Google will assign the folder to the root of your Drive. The only way to change this is to supply an `update` request indicating that you want to remove the parents of the folder that fall under the alias `root`.

In Python, it's as simple as this:

```
service.files().update(fileId=id, removeParents='root').execute()
```

Comment: Note that creating dangling/orphan files (files with no parents, not even the root) is possible, but then can be difficult to retrieve them / find them. https://support.google.com/drive/forum/AAAAOxCWsToRzdlHkBbE2w?hl=en

Comment: @tehhowch That is true, but in this case I'll be assigning a custom property to the folder so it should be hard to lose it ;-)